# Google map not loading content swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-places

Hi I am using the Google place picker but map is not loading. I tried every answer mentioned in stack overflow. Google map sdk is also enabled in console. Here is the screen shot..[image]

Comment: What is the SDK version?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR 2.6.0

Comment: Make sure you are using correct google map key. Or try to regenerate.

Comment: @PramodMore I am using the correct google map key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My app is multi language and i am saving the string against the key

> "Apple Languages"

due to this google map not loading and apple map crashed and give me

> array object at index 0 error

So if anyone getting this error and tried everything and app is in multi language try this solution.Hopefully it will help someone.

Comment: Hi I am having the same issue can you share your solution.

Comment: Hello,I am also having same issue, Would you please share solution for the same

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Please make sure that map API is enabled for the google map once in console.